# What should I look for when buying a table saw?

Tags: table-saw

I'm thinking about getting my first table saw. I'm a hobbyist but I still want to get something good.

I'm looking for a list of desirable features (safety, accuracy, usability, etc) as well as things to look out for and how to assert the tool's quality once I get it so it won't take me a lot of time to realize something is wrong with it.

Comment: *"I'm thinking about getting my first table saw"* I'm glad you began with this as I wanted to mention something I usually do when this comes up. I don't feel up to adding a competing Answer to flesh this out but before getting submerged in the choice of which TS to get be sure to fully assess *whether* you really want/need one. Many hobby woodworkers, and the occasional pro, do not own table saws. It's not because they can't afford one or its footprint (although both can be considerations) it tends to be because they've realised other tools are a better fit for what they actually need [contd]

Comment: .....(a bandsaw for example is far more versatile so could easily be prioritised), and/or due to the knowledge of how dangerous tables saws can be, well before flesh-sensing technology at least.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point. I have a circular saw and a jig saw. I feel I'm able to achieve my "flexible" cutting needs using it (and a couple jigs to go with the jig saw), the main reason I want to get a table saw is because i can't get the level of accuracy i would like using a circular saw. I tried making a couple jigs for that and i kinda failed.

Comment: Very welcome. A circular saw is one of *the* ancillary tools that can help take the place of what some use their TSs for. In fairness you simply can't take the place of *all* TS cuts (especially if used to its full potential) but you can do a heck of a lot of needed tasks using various other tools to pick up the slack. Obviously the type of work you intend to do is a factor, but circ saw + router can genuinely take its place in many workshops, and the addition of a benchtop bandsaw can add tons of useful functionality. Not to ignore the possible place of hand-tool work as well naturally.

Comment: Re. the circular saw and accuracy, we have a couple of recent Qs that might be able to help with some of that vis a vis cutting guides and so forth. And I happened to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfbaVv3lzwY) from Frank's Workbench at lunchtime today that has a little bit early on when he's cutting down the 2x6s.

Comment: I've got a router too, I'll look into using it for fine-tuning edges as well. I know it's done but haven't really looked into it.

Comment: *"I've got a router too, I'll look into using it for fine-tuning edges as well. I know it's done but haven't really looked into it."* We have a recent Q on that too :-) It's still on the first page so you just need to scroll down to find it.

Comment: After having bought a cheaper compact TS, I have to say that the most important thing is the Fence. OMG you will hate yourself if you get a cheap fence, and buying after market just to fix it is going to make you want to kick yourself for not buying a nicer saw in the first place. I'd recommend you up your budget to the 700 USD range for something with a good fence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many existing guides to purchasing first table saw.

[How to Buy Your First Table Saw and Get Started Using It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L8w6-8fc6A)

- Intro says *"the primary considerations you should have are your budget and your needs"*.

[Choosing A Table Saw – 13 Things To Consider Before Buying!](https://www.makefromwood.com/choosing-a-table-saw-13-things-to-consider-before-buying/)

- Base Type
- Table Space
- Extension Tables
- Rip Capacity
- Electrical
- Saw Blade Size
- Cut Depth
- Dust Collection
- Dado Blade Option
  **[Not available in many countries outside of America, considered too dangerous by lawmakers]**
- Fence Options
  [Stock fences on saws ($$-$$$) sometimes poor, many better 3rd party fences available. DIY fence for older saws can be **huge** upgrade.]
- Blade guard
- Riving Knife
- Saw Stop
  *"As mentioned before, table saws are the most dangerous machines in a woodworker’s shop based on ER visits."*

Not mentioned but I think very important is **miter gauge**. Stock miter gauge often weakest part, even on good brands can be junk. Many upgrade miter gauges now available, can be expensive. Some from China are of very high build quality but not overpriced, [China tools Ep.18 Does the best Miter Gauge come from China?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrjj5loLLoU)

[Why you should own a Table Saw](https://www.toolstop.co.uk/blog/knowledge-base/why-you-should-own-a-table-saw)
[Choosing Your First Table Saw](https://www.therecreationalwoodworker.com/blog/choosing-your-first-table-saw)
[How to Choose the Best Table Saw](https://woodandshop.com/best-table-saw-for-woodworking-power-tool-buying-guide-05/) (updated only 5 days ago!)
[The Right Table Saw for Your Shop](https://www.rockler.com/learn/the-right-table-saw-for-your-shop)
[Your first table saw: A step-by-step guide to making your first cuts.](https://woodworkingformeremortals.com/your-first-table-saw-a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-your-first-cuts-woodworking-basics/)

Added points possibly not covered in links

- **Most important to research table saw safe practice BEFORE FIRST USE.** You cannot trust many YouTubers to teach you table saw safety as **many ignore basic safety protocols**.
- Stock blades often poor. Starting budget should allow for purchase of 1-3 quality blades from reliable manufacturer.
- **TURN OFF POWER TO SAW WHEN CHANGING BLADE.**
- After you purchase you need to research crosscut sleds and zero clearance inserts. 1st important for safety during crosscuts, 2nd for quality of cut.
- Older saws can be upgraded with knee switch for huge safety upgrade.
- **Dust collection, dust collection, dust collection** if you will work inside.

Comment: The Dewalt 60v has a miter gauge that's gear driven on both sides. It's pretty sweet. "Rip Capacity" - is pretty much everything. That's basically the equivalent of *Will it Blend?*

Comment: @Mazura Perhaps you're confusing "miter gauge" and "rip fence"?

Comment: I am; never used that thing before. That's what chop saws are for and do it much safer.

Comment: @Mazura, no single-operator workshop with a table saw *needs* a chop saw. It's easily argued that they are superfluous in anything other than a commercial operation where multiple tools may need to be in use simultaneously.

Answer (score -3):

When buying a table saw, there are several key factors to consider.

**First, safety should be a top priority**. Look for features such as blade guards and a riving knife that help prevent accidents. Make sure the saw has a reliable and easy-to-use safety switch.

**Accuracy is another important aspect**. Check for a stable and sturdy fence that locks securely in place, as well as a miter gauge that slides smoothly and is easy to read. Look for a table saw with good dust collection capabilities to help keep your workspace clean.

**Usability is also a crucial consideration**. Look for a table saw that is user-friendly and has intuitive controls. Consider the size and weight of the saw, especially if you have limited space in your workshop or need to transport it frequently.

**When assessing the quality of the tool**, pay attention to the build materials and construction. Look for a well-built and durable table saw that will withstand heavy use. Read reviews from other users to get an idea of the tool's performance and reliability.

Overall, take the time to research and compare different table saw models, considering your specific needs and budget. It's a significant investment, so it's important to choose a table saw that meets your requirements and will serve you well for years to come.

Comment: This feels like it was machine generated, not written by a human. Can you confirm that you wrote this yourself please? After all, posting ChatGPT-based answers is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) across all SE sites.